# Port not redirected in embedded tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, embedded-tomcat-8, security-constraint

I have a situation where i need to redirect requests from a non `SSL` port to an `SSL` port. I came up with the following code but it doesn't seem to redirect.

```
baseConnector = tomcat.getConnector();
    if (sslEnabled) {
        sslConnector = new Connector();
        sslConnector.setAttribute("keyAlias", "tomcat");
        sslConnector.setAttribute("keystorePass", "mypassword");
        sslConnector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", "pathtofile");
        sslConnector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
        sslConnector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
        sslConnector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);
        sslConnector.setProtocol("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        sslConnector.setSecure(true);
        sslConnector.setScheme("https");
        sslConnector.setPort(8443);
        tomcat.getService().addConnector(sslConnector);
        baseConnector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like i had to add a security constraint to the context to redirect from a non-SSL port to a SSL port

Comment: that's right, this has to be done in the application